# Using Ionic Native Deeplinks to Load Angular Components

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic4, deep-linking, ionic-native

I have been searching the internet and found [a great youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qnapNnX-WI&t=31s) which is taking me closer to getting ionic deep links to work.

Using the android simulator, I can see that my current set up is matching to the route I am trying to use when accessing the **/match** path inside the app.

I will be firing this code on a push notification callback function eventually, but for testing, I am calling deeplinks on initializeApp().

I have used code pen like the tutorial suggests and this is giving some insight into what is happening when using the emulator. When the link is clicked I can see some information, which as of yesterday, I was struggling to find a way to suitably get access to such information.

codepen example:

```
<h1><a href="sideline://sidelineapp.io/match">Alert</a></h1>
```

I have my app.component.ts set up like this:

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      if(localStorage.getItem('config') !== null){
        localStorage.removeItem('config');
      }

      this.splashScreen.hide();

      timer(3000).subscribe(() => {
        this.showSplash = false;
      });

      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.oneSignalPush();
        console.log('onesignal');
      }

      this.deeplinks.route({
        '/match': StatsComponent,
      }).subscribe((match) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(match.$link.path));<-- this alerts the correct path
        this.router.navigate([match.$link.path]);<-- this routes to /match
        console.log('match', match)
      }, (nomatch) => {
        nomatch.$link
        alert(JSON.stringify(nomatch));
        console.log('no match', nomatch)
      })

    });
  }
```

the object which gets console logged looks like this (apologies just a picture):

[image]

I can see that $route is being found, but as the path requires the component for the view to render, like my app-routing.module.ts rather than an Ionic Page, the view doesn't render. The loading graphic just hangs and the component doesn't initialize after the route is found.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? I have seen examples of developers using angular modules for this, but not components. Is there something extra I need to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you're using Ionic, there's a convenience method that takes a reference to a NavController and handles the actual navigation for you:

```
this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.navController, {
  '/about-us': AboutPage,
  '/products/:productId': ProductPage
}).subscribe(match => {
    // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the      arguments to route()
    // match.$args - the args passed in the link
    // match.$link - the full link data
    console.log('Successfully matched route', match);
  }, nomatch => {
    // nomatch.$link - the full link data
    console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
  }
);
```

You can also get the reference from this [git repo](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-deeplinks-demo/blob/master/app/app.t).

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nandi.development

Comment: thanks Vicky. I got it working. I'll send up my code this afternoon to show how I got it working